# Can you add other configurations with SlowCheetah

Tags: .net, visual-studio, slowcheetah

I would like to add more app.configs other than just the debug and release. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a solution configuration for each app.*.config file and then rerun the transform.

1. In Visual Studio go to the **Build** menu > **Configuration Manager**
2. Beneath **Active solution configuration** select **<New...>**
   [image: Add solution configuration]
3. Enter a name. This will be the name in app.NAME.config.
4. Click OK and return to Solution Explorer.
5. Right-click **app-config** and select **Add Transform**. The new app.NAME.config will appear.
   [image]

Comment: I do already have 4 different solution configs for building. Slow Cheetah Add Transform doesn't nothing other then add the standard debug / release configs.

Comment: Check Configuration Manager to make sure all 4 configs show for your project. Sometimes new configs don't get added to all of the projects.

Comment: I've found that new configs for the solution do not show up for projects and new configs for a project are specific to that project.  It takes a bunch of repetitive work to manually add new configurations to all projects of a large solution, but it's the only method I know.